# Roadbuilding machine plowing through the Amazon rainforest using heat beam

Tags: story-identification, movie

In the 1960s I saw an animated film. Among other projected advances, there was a large machine that obliterated everything in its path by shining a road-wide beam of light ahead of it -- presumably a "heat ray" rather than a laser -- and leaving a new road behind it. My fragmented memory has a striking scene of this machine cutting through the Amazon rainforest at night, and it says much about those times that the theme was entirely one of progress, with not a thought for the environment, wildlife, or original inhabitants of the region.

UPDATE: In my original question, I evidently conflated two old memories, the other being a facetious car with concrete wheels bouncing along a rubber highway. As the sources of the two memories seem to be different, and the car with concrete wheels has definitely been found, I am splitting this part of the question off for a separate answer. Apologies!

Comment: Hmm.  It's animatronic, not animated, and it's individual cutting beams, not a single beam, but there's a video from the [General Motors Futurama exhibit at the 1964/1965 World’s Fair](https://youtu.be/2-5aK0H05jk?t=232) that shows laser tree cutting in a jungle diorama, with a large single-operation road-building machine, and in the video it appears that it might be night.

Comment: There was an episode of Thunderbirds which involved a road building machine similar to the one you describe - https://thunderbirds.fandom.com/wiki/Gray_%26_Houseman_Road_Construction_Vehicle . There is also another Thunderbirds episode with a machine which chopped down trees to clear forests - https://thunderbirds.fandom.com/wiki/Path_of_Destruction. Both episodes were transmitted in the '60s

Comment: @DavidW, Ross Millikan: If either of you would care to describe the animatronic GM Futurama exhibit as an answer, with link, then I will gladly designate it as the answer to this question. As I mentioned earlier, I think that I conflated two childhood memories, and the other source has already been acknowledged. I attended the [Futurama exhibit](http://www.nywf64.com/gm06.shtml), along with millions of other people, in 1964 or 1965.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it might be animatronic instead of animated, you might be remembering the road-building machine shown in [General Motors' Futurama exhibit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futurama_(New_York_World%27s_Fair)) at the [1964/1965 World’s Fair](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1964_New_York_World%27s_Fair).  It uses lasers to clear the jungle and a massive machine that does all the road construction.  Note that it's not a massive heat beam (à la *War of the Worlds*), but directed cutting lasers.

You can see the diorama showing the jungle clearing and road building at 3:52 in this video of the ride:

The lighting makes it appear as though it's night, and because it's animatronic, it's in motion as though it were working.